# getting an InvalidProgramException error in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run a PowerShell command from within C#.

This is the code

```
PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential("domain.inet\adminuser", domainAdminPswrd);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri("http://exchangeserver/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", Credential);

connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
```

When I run the above code, the compiler halts at 'Runspace runspace' (second to last line) with the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred
>
> Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

I have been trying to troubleshoot, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Which .NET framework are you on?

Comment: I'm on .net 4.5 and VS Premium 2013

Comment: I resolved this issue by installing KB2819745 on the machine running the c# program. (not the server I am connecting to)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by installing KB2819745 on the machine running the c# program. (not the server I am connecting to)